# How do I make a substitution to an expression inside a derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Pardon if I didn't ask the question correctly.  Still trying to figure out the language.
I have the following expression:
$$energy=\frac{1}{2}R_s^{'}[t]^2==\frac{4}{3}G\pi\rho R_s[t]^2$$

```
energy = (1/2)*Derivative[1][Subscript[R, s]][t]^2 == (4/3)*G*
   Pi*\[Rho]*Subscript[R, s][t]^2
```

I have the following identity:
$$R_s[t]==a[t]r_s$$
When I make this substitution:
$$energy/.R_s[t]\rightarrow a[t]r_s$$

```
energy /. Subscript[R, s][t] -> a[t]*Subscript[r, s]
```

I get this result:

$$\frac{1}{2}R_s^{'}[t]^2 == \frac{4}{3}G\pi\rho R_s[t]^2$$

(1/2)*Derivative[1][Subscript[R, s]][t]^2 == (4/3)*G*Pi*[Rho]*a[t]^2*
Subscript[r, s]^2

What do I need to do for the derivative $R_s^{'}[t]^2$ to understand the substitution.  I was expecting the result to be:

$$\frac{1}{2}r_s a'[t]^2 == \frac{4}{3}G\pi\rho (r_s a[t])^2$$

**EDIT**: Accessing external code is a bad idea and should be avoided at all costs.  It's just one more thing that can go wrong when sharing code.  I'm looking for a solution that solves this problem with the native Mathematica instructions.

Comment: Why isn't R_s in the right hand side of the final result substituted?

Comment: Please see the duplicate thread and topics linked there.

Comment: energy /. {Subscript[R, s] -> (Subscript[r, s] a[#] &)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
energy /. Subscript[R, s] -> Function[t, a[t]*Subscript[r, s]]
```

> [image]

Or using linked answer:

```
DChange[energy, Subscript[R, s][t] == a[t]*Subscript[r, s]]
```

Comment: I can't speak for everyone with the same problem, but your first solution seems to be the simplest one as it's a single line and uses just Mathematica.  I'm not a big fan of external code in my solutions.  One more thing to go wrong.

Comment: @Quarkly sure, fair enough. Linked topic links to old solutions that are basically the same as the first line here so the duplicate works like a central hub rather than the only way to go. `DChange` uses the same method btw.